# Kohana ORM после изменения структуры таблицы (добавления нового поля), фреймворк его не видит

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, orm

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста! Я добавил новое поле в phpMyAdmin и теперь сайт не работает - выскакивает ошибка о том, что поле не существует:

```
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: The url property does not exist in the Model_Sportpit_Product class
```

Я добавил поле url. Если удаляю его, то все работает. Но мне оно нужно.
Как я понял, при первом обращении Kohana к таблице, ее структура сохраняется. И если изменить структуру, будет ошибка. Как найти файл, который Kohana сохранила? Чтобы удалить его и сделать так, чтобы фреймворк считал, будто это первое обращение к таблице.﻿

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте.

В моделях Kohana есть свойство, отвечающее за поля и их тип, как на примере ниже:

```
protected $_table_columns = array (
    'id' => array ('type' => 'smallint'),
    'parent_id' => array ('type' => 'smallint'),
    'title' => array ('type' => 'char'),
);
```

Полагаю, что нужно указать поле в модели, которая относится к таблице.
Вот посмотрите, быть может вам нужно дописать в массив поле таблицы и его тип, и все заработает?

В вашем случае в файле модели: `/application/classes/Model/Sportpit/Product.php`